# iOS -deprecated permission-facebook friends birthday using Graph API

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook-graph-api

I am new to iOS .
I am trying to **fetch birthdays of all friends** from a Facebook account.
I followed [Developers.facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/)

I have requested all the necessary permissions :`user_friends`, `friends_birthday`, `read_stream`. I have also set permissions in the *Graph Api Explorer*.

First I used the graph path : `@"/me/friends?fields=name,id,birthday"`. It is returning *only name and id* of friends *who have used the app*.

I searched in the web and tried out `@"/me/taggable_friends"`. It is given in the developer site that we can access only three fields for this taggable_friends : `id,name,picture`.

I found that **facebook has deprecated friends details permissions**. Please refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

> -(void)pickFriendsClick 
>   {
>
> ```
> NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"user_birthday",@"friends_hometown",@"friends_birthday",@"friends_location",nil];
> if (![[FBSession activeSession]isOpen]) {
>
>     if (APP.fb) {
>
>         APP.fb =[[FBSession alloc]initWithPermissions:permissions];
>     }
> }
>
> FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"/me/taggable_friends"];
> [friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
>     NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
>     NSMutableArray *friends= [data mutableCopy];
>     NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"updated_time" ascending:TRUE];
>     [friends sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
>
>     for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in friends) {
>         NSLog(@"%@:%@", [friend name],[friend birthday]);
>     }}]; }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full list of permissions that have been removed from v2.0. Your app should not ask for any of the following from Facebook Ver 2.0:

```
create_event
manage_friendlists
read_requests
user_checkins
user_notes
user_online_presence
user_questions
user_subscriptions
xmpp_login
friends_about_me
friends_actions.books
friends_actions.fitness
friends_actions.music
friends_actions.news
friends_actions.video
friends_actions:APP_NAMESPACE
friends_activities
friends_birthday
friends_checkins
friends_education_history
friends_events
friends_games_activity
friends_groups
friends_hometown
friends_interests
friends_likes
friends_location
friends_notes
friends_online_presence
friends_photos
friends_questions
friends_relationships
friends_relationship_details
friends_religion_politics
friends_status
friends_subscriptions
friends_videos
friends_website
friends_work_history
```

ref : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

you Can fetch only friends

```
1. id,name,picture only.
```

Comment: your coding is fine, but Facebook integration is changed/restricted in v2.0,

Comment: do u need any more reference , what happened on my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! I checked out the developers site and finally modified my requirements .

Answer (score 0):

I have fetched friends by this code in new facebook sdk. This might be helpful.

```
NSArray *permissions =     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", @"user_birthday",@"friends_hometown",@"friends_birthday",@"friends_location",@"publish_stream",@"user_friends",@"public_profile",nil];

[self appDelegate].session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];

[[self appDelegate].session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                        FBSessionState status,
                                                        NSError *error) {

    if(!error)
    {
        NSLog(@"success");
        [self fetchFriends];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"failure");
    }



}];
```

then method fetch friend is

```
-(void)fetchFriends
{
    if ([self appDelegate].session.isOpen)
    {
        [FBSession setActiveSession:[self appDelegate].session];
        FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"/me/friends?fields=name,picture,birthday,location"];
        [ friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

            NSLog(@"response : %@",data);

            for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in data)
            {
                NSLog(@"name : %@ , bday : %@", [friend name],[friend birthday]);

                [tempArray addObject:friend];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me the link where you downloaded the new SDK ?

Comment: but we cannot get all friends .. we can only get names of friends who are using our app

Comment: That will not happen every time. It is also depends on Fb account. Try it on different accounts Than see the difference.

Comment: No it is not avilable. You can refer this [**link**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1)

Comment: I know that, and I have experienced it well. It works but not all time.