# Facebook friends Location info in iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

Any one having a idea how to get Facebook friends location details from Facebook profile.

I am getting these details (id,name,gender,email, picture) using this graph API.

I also need location information.

Thanks!

Comment: refrer this u can't fetch friends location in new ver 2.0 from Facebook , need ref use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859046/ios-list-of-facebook-friends-birthday-using-graph-api/24859147#24859147

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 0):

To get friends location for 1.0 graph api,you can use following code.

```
 if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {




[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=name,location,installed,picture"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          NSDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *my,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {

                          NSDictionary *resultDictionary = (NSDictionary *)my;



                          if ([resultDictionary valueForKey:@"data"]) {
                             NSString * latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[my2 valueForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"latitude"]];

                             NSString *longitude=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[my2 valueForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"longitude"]];

                          }



}];
}
```

**Important Note** me/friends will only return you those friends who have authorized your app since graph api 2.0 as mentioned here in [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) And all friends info are removed as mentioned except basic info like `name , id , picture` as [mentioned here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids)

> In v1.0, it was possible to ask for permissions that would allow an
>   app to see a limited amount of friend data, such as a person's
>   friend's likes, their birthdays, and so on.
>
> In v2.0, those permissions have all been removed. It's no longer
>   possible for an app to see data from a person's friends unless those
>   friends have also logged into the app and granted permission for the
>   app to see it that data