# Get birthdays of Friends who are using my App

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to extract birthdays of friends who are using my app; I'm unable to access it.

```
FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=name,birthday"];
[friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
{
    NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in data)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@:%@:%@", [friend id], [friend name], [friend birthday]);
    }
}
```

Permissions on didLoad:

```
self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends", @"friends_birthday"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

facebook is remove some of the accessibility of friend in Facebook V 2.1. friend birthday is also removed. so you can't get the date of friend birthday.

**List of All friends_* permissions has been removed. They include:**

```
friends_about_me
friends_actions.books
friends_actions.fitness
friends_actions.music
friends_actions.news
friends_actions.video
friends_actions:APP_NAMESPACE
friends_activities
friends_birthday
friends_checkins
friends_education_history
friends_events
friends_games_activity
friends_groups
friends_hometown
friends_interests
friends_likes
friends_location
friends_notes
friends_online_presence
friends_photos
friends_questions
friends_relationships
friends_relationship_details
friends_religion_politics
friends_status
friends_subscriptions
friends_videos
friends_website
friends_work_history
```

[Facebook reference link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions)

Comment: Can you give me the exact link where it is written about removal of friends birthday?

Comment: i give you link below answare.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is restrict the some functionalities of friends list and details in Facebook V 2.1. You can fetch only:

1. id
2. name
3. picture only

[Documentation reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/taggable_friends).

Comment: need a link check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859046/ios-deprecated-permission-facebook-friends-birthday-using-graph-api