# Facebook Graph API v2.3 query @"me/taggable_friends" give details of all friends without birthday . how to get friends details with their birthday?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using facebook sdk v 2.3 and try to find friends birthdate.using query @"me/friends" we can find only that friends who using same app. but i need to find all friends with their details with birthday.
I am using @"me/taggable_friends" this query gives the detail of friends without birthday. So Give me the permission name or query any other way to get all friends with birthday.

I am using code like..

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/taggable_friends?limit=10" parameters:nil]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id strong textresult, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
             }
         }];
    }
```

Comment: Don't sure that works now, but some mouths before, it was working :  @"me/taggable_friends?fields=name,birthday"

Comment: in sdk v2.3 me/taggable_friends?fields=name,birthday this query gives only name and id it is not giving birthday. which sdk you use for this. is there any solution in sdk v-2.3

Comment: Have you see this post ?  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859046/ios-deprecated-permission-facebook-friends-birthday-using-graph-api

Comment: For somes permission you have to submit your app to facebook. If you want test the app without submit, make sure your facebook user is register as developer of your facebook app.

Answer (score 2):

`taggable_friends` is for tagging friends only, you are not supposed to use it for anything else.

That being said, friend permissions are gone, **it is not possible at all to get the birthday of a friend**. The only way to get the birthday of a friend is by authorizing that friend too, with the `user_birthday` permission.

Btw, you also need to go through [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) for `user_birthday`. And you would need to go through a review process with `taggable_friends` too, it will never get approved for anything else than tagging.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and first approved your app on facebook developer account. after that you can easily access friend detail with birth date.

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
loginView.delegate = self;
loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends",@"image"];

BOOL status=[[RootAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] netStatus];

if(status)
 {
__block FBSessionStateHandler runOnceHandler = ^(FBSession *session,
                                                 FBSessionState status,
                                                 NSError *error) {
};

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_birthday",@"user_friends",@"user_photos"]
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                  FBSessionState status,
                                                  NSError *error) {
                                  if (!error) {
                                      if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen){

                            /// write here your code whatever you want.

                                      }
                                  }
                                  if (runOnceHandler) {
                                      runOnceHandler(session, status, error);
                                      runOnceHandler = nil;
                                  }

                              }
 ];


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

using taggable-friend you can get only friends - **id**, **first name**, **last name**, **middle_name**, **name**, **picture**

[taggable-friend](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-taggable-friend/)

Field of Taggable-friend in graph Explorer as below.

[image]

Comment: ID means user id or session ID. Because I am using same API and did not get the userID. please suggest.

Comment: ID == UserID of taggable friends

Comment: But in response I am receiving ID="AaLYBzZzHdzCmlytqyMAjO0OLDZIOs74Urn93ikeRmmTB3vX_Xl81OYUt4XnoWG0BDLuX67umVkheVdDjzyvm0fcqMqu84GgM9JnNHc-1B63eg" instead of id=70523*****46443. So please suggest.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  The ID from taggable-friends is not a user-id.  It's something else.

Comment: you don´t get the user id, you get a tagging token. and you are not supposed to use taggable_friends for anything else than tagging. either way, it´s not possible at all to get birthdays of friends if they did not authorize your app.